# Using beautiful soup 4 to scrape URLS within a <p class="postbody"> tag and save them to a text file

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I realize this is probably incredibly straightforward but please bear with me. I'm trying to use beautifulsoup 4 to scrape a website that has a list of blog posts for the urls of those posts. The  tag that I want is within an  tag. There are multiple  tags that include a header and then a link that I want to capture. This is the code I'm working with:

```
with io.open('TPNurls.txt', 'a', encoding='utf8') as logfile:
   snippet = soup.find_all('p', class="postbody")
   for link in snippet.find('a'):
       fulllink = link.get('href')
       logfile.write(fulllink + "\n")
```

The error I'm getting is:

> AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find'

I understand that means "head" is a set and beautifulsoup doesn't let me look for  tags within a set. But then how can I do this? I need it to find the entire set of  tags and then look for the  tag within each one and then save each one on a separate line to a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual reason for the error is that `snippet` is a result of `find_all()` call and is basically a list of results, there is no `find()` function available on it. Instead, you meant:

```
snippet = soup.find('p', class_="postbody")
for link in snippet.find_all('a'):
    fulllink = link.get('href')
    logfile.write(fulllink + "\n")
```

Also, note the use of `class_` here - `class` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as a keyword argument here. See [Searching by CSS class](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) for more info.

---

Alternatively, make use of [`CSS selectors`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for link in snippet.select('p.postbody a'):
   fulllink = link.get('href')
   logfile.write(fulllink + "\n")
```

`p.postbody a` would match all `a` tags inside the `p` tag with class `postbody`.

Comment: FWIW, `snippet = soup.find('p', 'postbody')` will also match tags with `class="postbody"`. Use of `_class` is explicit (which is better than implicit), so is probably better.

Comment: @mhawke yeah, and `soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'postbody'})` is even more explicit :)

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's still giving me a ResultSet error with your code.

Comment: @JolijtTamanaha there is smth with the code you are using, can you post the complete code you have now? (include into the question) Thanks.

Comment: hi thank you both for your help, I ended up simplifying it by looking for the same link within a different tag but used your more explicit code and it worked

Comment: @JolijtTamanaha great, thanks for sharing. See if the answer can be accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
snippet = soup.find_all('p', class="postbody")
for link in snippet.find('a'):
```

Here `snippet` is a `bs4.element.ResultSet` type object. So you are getting this error. But the elements of this `ResultSet` object are `bs4.element.Tag` type where you can apply `find` method.

Change your code like this,

```
snippet = soup.find_all("p", { "class" : "postbody" })
for link in snippet:
    if link.find('a'):
        fulllink = link.a['href']
        logfile.write(fulllink + "\n")
```

Comment: can you provide some input data?

Comment: hi thanks for your help but I ended up simplifying it by looking for the same link within a different tag.